# I want to run apache storm in local mode but I cannot activate the UI

Tags: apache-storm, nimbus

As it says I can activate nimbus and supervisor without issues but for some reason the UI gets completely stuck  when I run `nimbus ui`.

The following is my error message

```
org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusLeaderNotFoundException: Could not find leader nimbus from seed hosts ["127.0.0.1"]. Did you specify a valid list of nimbus hosts for config nimbus.seeds?
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClientAs(NimbusClient.java:111)
    at org.apache.storm.ui.core$supervisor_summary.invoke(core.clj:499)
    at org.apache.storm.ui.core$fn__9565.invoke(core.clj:1128)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.compojure.core$make_route$fn__5976.invoke(core.clj:100)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.compojure.core$if_route$fn__5964.invoke(core.clj:46)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.compojure.core$if_method$fn__5957.invoke(core.clj:31)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.compojure.core$routing$fn__5982.invoke(core.clj:113)
    at clojure.core$some.invoke(core.clj:2570)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.compojure.core$routing.doInvoke(core.clj:113)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:139)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:632)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.compojure.core$routes$fn__5986.invoke(core.clj:118)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.middleware.cors$wrap_cors$fn__8891.invoke(cors.clj:149)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.middleware.json$wrap_json_params$fn__8838.invoke(json.clj:56)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.middleware.multipart_params$wrap_multipart_params$fn__6618.invoke(multipart_params.clj:118)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.middleware.reload$wrap_reload$fn__7901.invoke(reload.clj:22)
    at org.apache.storm.ui.helpers$requests_middleware$fn__6871.invoke(helpers.clj:50)
    at org.apache.storm.ui.core$catch_errors$fn__9758.invoke(core.clj:1428)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.middleware.keyword_params$wrap_keyword_params$fn__6538.invoke(keyword_params.clj:35)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.middleware.nested_params$wrap_nested_params$fn__6581.invoke(nested_params.clj:84)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.middleware.params$wrap_params$fn__6510.invoke(params.clj:64)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.middleware.multipart_params$wrap_multipart_params$fn__6618.invoke(multipart_params.clj:118)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.middleware.flash$wrap_flash$fn__6833.invoke(flash.clj:35)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.middleware.session$wrap_session$fn__6819.invoke(session.clj:98)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.util.servlet$make_service_method$fn__6368.invoke(servlet.clj:127)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.util.servlet$servlet$fn__6372.invoke(servlet.clj:136)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.util.servlet.proxy$javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet$ff19274a.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:654)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1320)
    at org.apache.storm.logging.filters.AccessLoggingFilter.handle(AccessLoggingFilter.java:47)
    at org.apache.storm.logging.filters.AccessLoggingFilter.doFilter(AccessLoggingFilter.java:39)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:93)
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:28)
    at org.apache.storm.ui.helpers$x_frame_options_filter_handler$fn__6964.invoke(helpers.clj:189)
    at org.apache.storm.ui.helpers.proxy$java.lang.Object$Filter$abec9a8f.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1291)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:247)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:210)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1291)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:443)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1044)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:372)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:978)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:369)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:486)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:933)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:995)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My configuration for storm.yaml is virtually this:

https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/conf/defaults.yaml

Except that the mode is `local`and not distributed. I also tested by calling the host "localhost" or "127.0.0.1". Both ways, the connection does not work. Nimbus and supervisor get started without error messages either.

Comment: can you show your storm.yaml file configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across the same problem, that is my solution:

1. stop zookeeper
2. delete zookeeper data directory
3. start zookeeper again